# Ruby issues while running sensu checks

Tags: ruby, sensu

I am getting the below error while trying to run the sensu checks my ruby version is ruby 2.1.6p336 (2015-04-13 revision 50298) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

> /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- sensu-plugin/check/cli (LoadError)
>   from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' from ./check-load.rb:30:in `main>'

Please guide me on how to fix the issue.

Comment: The error message is not complete. Show us the full stack trace

Comment: Hi Sorry for late reply my sensu gives me this out put

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error `cannot load such file -- sensu-plugin/check/cli` indicates that the gem `sensu-plugin` cannot be found.

Ensure that you have this gem installed on the system you're running the check on - you should be able to install it with:

```
gem install sensu-plugin
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36116588/4039725, another possibility is: It could also be a permissions issue in directory `/opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems`. Go to the directory and do `chmod -R 755 *`. And then restart Sensu service.